# How can i make ffmpeg pick the right file?

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg

I've been trying to make ffmpeg pick up files from a folder and merge them together.

The code i have for merging the audio and video is:

`ffmpeg -i video.m2v -i audio.wav -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 %orginal_name%.mxf`

This works but i chnage the `%origninal_name` to the name of the video file.

Im currently using a watch folder in FFAStrans to pick the video file up and using custom ffmpeg comand to run the command. The problem i'm having is that i have to specify the video and audio file name.

The folder has over 100 video and audio file and they have the same name so if ita s food show it would be

`category_name_episode_HighRandomVariable.m2v` for video 
`category_name_episode_HighRandomVariableDifferentFromVideo.wav` for audio
example of this is 
`food_johnsCooking_EP1_High745548.m2v` and
`food_johnsCooking_EP1_High8547885874.wav`

im using regext as well but dont really know how to use in in FFAStrans but the command looks like this. 
`$regext("%s_original_name%","(.+)_High")`

Does anyone know how i can set it up so i can get the correct audio and video file to merge and at the same time make sure all other videos and audio files are done without me having to change the `ffmpeg -i` to the next video and audio name.

Any Help or advice is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about **FFAStrans** but you can write simple python or bash script to achieve your task.

Comment: any help with the bash script? @Vencat

Comment: Could you tell me what are the video and audio formats you going to have in the folder, only .m2v & wav .? also is it possible to add "video" and "audio" in the name of file like **food_johnsCooking_EP1_High745548_video.m2v** / **food_johnsCooking_EP1_High745548_audio.wav**. What OS you are using -Windows or Linux .?

Comment: All videos are m2v and all audios are wav, im not sure if ill be able to add video and audio at the end of there name. I'm using Windows

Answer (score 0):

This script might helps you. I'm assuming that each episode has only one audio/video file with .wav and .m2v format.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

file_list = sorted(os.listdir(sys.argv[1]))
src_path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]) + '//'

for i,k in zip(file_list[0::2], file_list[1::2]): #checks the episode has only one audio/video file
    if((i.split('_')[2] == k.split('_')[2]) and i.split('.')[1] != k.split('.')[1]):
        dst_dir = os.path.expanduser('~\\Videos\\FFmpegOutput\\') + i.split('.')[0] + ".mxf"
        ffmpeg_cmd = "ffmpeg -i " + src_path + i + " -i " + src_path + k + " -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 " + dst_dir
        subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, shell=True).communicate()

    else:
        print("Video or Audio file is missing for episode {}".format(i.split('.')[0]))
        break
```

You can run this script as below.

> python script_file ["Path to your audio/video folder"]
>
> Example : python script.py c://Users//MediaFolder

It will save multiplexed videos in *Videos folder*.

Comment: thanks so much, im still trying to make it work with mine and understand the code

Comment: I'm picking video and audio file for **ffmpeg command** by episode number and file extension, for example ( EP1 , .wav, .m2v). That means, I'm assuming that you are not having more than 2 files per episode.